# How to use angularjs routeParams properly

Tags: angularjs, routes

I'm just wondering how to use `routeParams` correctly.
I wrote code like this in app.js:

```
.when('/product', {
    templateUrl: 'views/product.html',
    controller: 'ProductController',
    title: ''
})
.when('/product/:productId', {
    templateUrl: 'views/product_detail.html',
    controller: 'ProductDetailController',
    title: ''
})
.when('/product/new', {
    templateUrl: 'views/product_new.html',
    controller: 'ProductController',
    title: ''
})
```

Here's the thing: I want to use URI named `'/product/new'`
but it goes `'/product/:productId'`.. (`product_detail.html`)

I want to how to use `'/product/:productId'` and `'/product/new'` both.

Is there any way to route like that?

Comment: Change the order write `/product/new` before `/product/:productId` .

Comment: OMG Thanks a lot!!! It works very well. xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the order in which you do routing to:

```
.when('/product', {
     templateUrl: 'views/product.html',
     controller: 'ProductController',
     title: ''
})
.when('/product/new', {
      templateUrl: 'views/product_new.html',
      controller: 'ProductController',
      title: ''
})
.when('/product/:productId', {
      templateUrl: 'views/product_detail.html',
      controller: 'ProductDetailController',
      title: ''
})
```